# webpack eslint error messages

Tags: webpack, eslint

This might be a strange question but since I'm new to Webpack, I was wondering if it's normal that e.g. the eslint error messages seem to be very long with some "chunks" above the error messages? In some cases the "chunks" at the top are even longer than in my example and I couldn't find any way to get rid of them (I don't see why I would need them). Is there any configuration that I forgot to add?

I'm using the [VueJS webpack simple template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) and added the eslint loader to it. I also tried the Stylelint plugin for Webpack and the error messages looked the same (confusing / unclear because of all the "chunks").

```
   Hash: 84d43d1c3599310c692c
    Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.28
    Time: 227ms
    chunk    {0} build.js (main) 481 kB [entry]
       [46] ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/component/Component.vue 182 bytes {0} [built]
       [88] ./src/component/Component.vue 1.76 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
       [89] ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler.js?id=data-v-104cb767!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/component/Component.vue 412 bytes {0} [built]
         + 94 hidden modules

    ERROR in ./src/App.vue

    /Users/dd/Documents/vue/src/App.vue
      16:5   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2  indent
      19:8   error  Missing semicolon                             semi
      21:4   error  Missing semicolon                             semi

    ✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)

     @ ./src/main.js 2:0-28
     @ multi main

    ERROR in ./src/component/Component.vue

    /Users/dd/Documents/vue/src/component/Component.vue
       9:5  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2  indent
      13:8  error  Missing semicolon                             semi
      15:4  error  Missing semicolon                             semi

    ✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)

     @ ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue 11:0-50
     @ ./src/App.vue
     @ ./src/main.js
     @ multi main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Webpack 2 docs on `Stats`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/):

> The stats option lets you precisely control what bundle information gets displayed. This can be a nice middle ground if you don't want to use `quiet` or `noInfo` because you want some bundle information, but not all of it.

In your `webpack.config.js` you can provide a `devServer` object at the top level export that has a property `stats`.

To turn off the display of chunks, add this to your config:

```
module.exports = {
  ...,

  devServer: {
    stats: {
      chunks: false
    }
  },

  ...
}
```